# d3.attrTween() not animating smoothly

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to call `.attrTween()` to animate the `y` property of an object smoothly.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
let svg = d3.select('svg')

svg.append('text')
  .attr({ x: 100, y: 100 })
  .text('I should be animated smoothly')

// animate consecutively through all positions
let positions = [10, 20, 15, 35, 70, 50, 30, 10, 30, 45]

svg.transition()
  .duration(10000)
  .ease('linear')
  .selectAll('text')
  .attrTween('y', function() {
    return function(t) {
       return positions[Math.floor(t * 10)]
    }
  })
```

Here's jsfiddle if you want to take a look: https://jsbin.com/ceronufuha/edit?html,js,output

*(Of course this is an over-simplified example.)*

Why does the animation is not smooth, am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code would not be smooth as it never [interpolates](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#d3_interpolate) between values.  On each tick you essentially find an index and "jump" to it.  If you want to animate between each of those values over the course of 10 seconds you would need to write it more like below.  I'm using `.transition()...attr()` which automatically creates an interpolater between the current y value and the next y value.

```js
let svg = d3.select('svg')

let text = svg.append('text')
  .attr({ x: 100, y: 100 })
  .text('I should be animated smoothly')

let positions = [10, 20, 15, 35, 70, 50, 30, 10, 30, 45]

nextMove(0);

function nextMove(i){
  text.transition()
    .duration(10000 / positions.length)
    .ease('linear')
    .attr('y', positions[i])
    .each('end', function(){
      i += 1;
      if (i < positions.length){
        nextMove(i);
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg height="400" width="400"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```